# How can I use 50fps media in iMovie 11 and avoid a frame drop to 30fps?

Tags: framerate, imovie

My photo camera records FullHD video at 50fps, and when I import the videos into iMovie (version 10.1.2 according to the app store) the frame rate stays there, I can see smooth videos playing in the library. However, when I drag a 50fps video to the timeline of an empty project, the frame rate is visibly reduced, and when I export the video I get a 30fps movie.

Is there anything I can do to maintain the 50fps through the edition process and into the output?

Answer (score 1):

While it is unfortunate that iMovie drops by default from 50fps to 30fps, it also upscales videos to 60fps if the project is started with a 60fps clip! I've ended making myself a one second 60fps dummy clip which I drag **first** into the project line. After dropping this dummy clip, I verify that the archive export dialog shows 60fps FullHD option, then add the other 50fps clips. At the end I remove the 60fps dummy clip and the project still allows exportation at 60fps.

In this situation iMovie will upscale the 50fps video to 60fps, generating a duplicate frame every five to compensate. Still, this is **much** better than dropping from 50 to 30 frames.

The most important thing to remember is that the option to export at 60fps is only available if the **first** clip dragged into the project is recorded at 60fps. If you already have a full project at 30fps dragging the 60fps clip won't help. So remember, drag always the 60fps dummy clip first!

Comment: Sounds to me like iMovie desperately needs to learn about the PAL world.  I would file a bug report with Apple if I were you.